# Log accepted packets with ufw

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm using ufw on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I want to log both dropped *and* accepted packets (I am aware this will generate a lot of logs).

I can do this by increasing the ufw log level with `ufw logging high` - but I also want to log some additional information that isn't included by default (TCP options and sequence number), so that's not going to work for me.

I believe the correct place to add custom logging rules is `/etc/ufw/before.rules`, and I've added this at the end of the file, just before the `COMMIT`:

```
-A INPUT -j LOG --log-tcp-options --log-tcp-sequence --log-prefix "[MY_PREFIX] "
-A FORWARD -j LOG --log-tcp-options --log-tcp-sequence --log-prefix "[MY_PREFIX] "
```

However, this is only logging dropped packets, not accepted ones. I guess this is something to do with the order of iptables rules, but I don't see anything else in `before.rules` that would short-circuit logging of accepted packets.

A couple of further constraints are that I don't want to log any outbound connections, or any loopback traffic.

Any ideas on how I can log both dropped and accepted packets with extra information?

Answer (score 0):

`-A` *appends* rules at the end of the `iptables` chain.

If you want to log every packet, before anything else, try using `-I`:

```
-I INPUT -j LOG --log-tcp-options --log-tcp-sequence --log-prefix "[MY_PREFIX] "
-I FORWARD -j LOG --log-tcp-options --log-tcp-sequence --log-prefix "[MY_PREFIX] "
```

That said, the best way to address these issues is to create **new chains** and modify your rules to use those chains instead of the standard ones.

As a (simple) example, you can have two new targets:

```
iptables -N LOG_DROP
iptables -N LOG_ACCEPT
```

and create "default" rules as

```
iptables -A LOG_DROP -j LOG --log-tcp-options --log-tcp-sequence --log-prefix "[MY_PREFIX] "
iptables -A LOG_DROP -j DROP

iptables -A LOG_ACCEPT -j LOG --log-tcp-options --log-tcp-sequence --log-prefix "[MY_PREFIX] "
iptables -A LOG_ACCEPT -j ACCEPT
```

Then on your rules you can "send" to `LOG_DROP` instead of `DROP` and `LOG_ACCEPT` instead of `ACCEPT`:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j LOG_DROP # Log and drop input packets to port 22
```

Comment: A couple of further constraints I forgot to menion are that I don't want to log outbound traffic, or loopback traffic - are any changes needed for that? `before.rules` already contains some stuff related to loopback at least, but I'm not sure if that has any impact

Comment: @Cocowalla simply `-j LOG_*` only in chains you need, `i.e.` `INPUT` and `FORWARD`. I'll update my answer.